# Persistent server side Facebook authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala

I am trying to pull a public feed from the graph onto my site. I'm currently doing this with the Koala gem for Ruby on Rails.

My problem is that I can not figure out if it is possible to silently maintain authentication so as not to interrupt service. I do not want my user to be authenticated, just myself using a server side connection.

Can this be done? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a Facebook app set up. To get a public page's posts, you will need to use your app access token. Note that this is different from the app id and secret specified in your app configuration on Facebook's developer site. Koala's OAuth class provides a method to get it.

Here's how to do it:

```
oauth            = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new Facebook::APP_ID, Facebook::SECRET
app_access_token = oauth.get_app_access_token
graph            = Koala::Facebook::API.new app_access_token
graph.get_connections("depechemode", "posts")
```

(I'm a Depeche Mode fan.)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean, you want to pull a public page's feed and display it on your website, without your website's users needing to login to facebook? Please provide more detail.